# 見える versus 見られる

Tags: meaning

Which one is correct?

1. メガネをかけると見えます。
2. メガネをかけると見られます。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one is most likely the one you want. Here is how to think about the difference between the two:

見える is used when the scene naturally enters your eyes, describing your ability to see.

- I can see with glasses on. メガネをかけると見えます。
- It's a clear day so I can see far off into the distance. 晴れているので遠くが見えます。
- These letters are too small for me to see clearly. 文字が小さくてよく見えません。

見られる is used to show potential based on some condition.

- I don't have a Blu-ray player so I can't watch the movie. ブルーレイプレイヤーを持っていないからこの映画が見られません。

It can sometimes be a difficult distinction to make when thinking about it in terms of English. In my experience the former is much more common than the latter.

Note that 聞こえる vs 聞ける is a similar case.

Comment: 遠くまで見える or 遠くが見える ＞ 遠く見える.  Nice answer, though.

Comment: "遠くが見える is not really said." >> ?? We say it!  "遠く見える is a better way of saying it than 遠くまで見える" >> ?? We don't say 遠く見える, but we use 遠くまで見える！  @IwakamiSensei What's your source? Are you a native Japanese speaker?

Comment: 遠く見える is commonly used and it usually means 遠くに見える or 遠くにあるように見える, I think. If the speaker who is saying 「晴れているので遠く見えます」 actually means 遠くまで見える or 遠くが見える, using the phrase 遠く見えます is a little strange because the nuance is different. But if the speaker actually means 遠くにあるように見える（現実の距離より遠く離れた位置にあるように見える）, saying 遠く見えます sounds natural to me (I'm Japanese, by the way). …という見方もできると思うのですが、いかがでしょうか。

Comment: 「It's a clear day so I can see far off into the distance.」の意味は、「晴れているので遠く見えます。」ではなくて、「(今日は)晴れているので遠く**まで** (よく)見えます。」か「(今日は)晴れているので遠く**が** (よく)見えます。」でしょうね。I can see far off into the distance と言うときに「遠く見える」とは言いません。「遠く見えます。」は、「 **何かが** (実際より)遠く見えます。」という意味になるでしょう。「晴れているので、XXがいつもより遠く見える。」とか「晴れているので、XXが実際より遠く見える。」なら、(意味はわかりませんが)文法的にはおかしくないと思います。

Comment: HiruneDiverさん、chocoさん、ありがとうございます。
教えることができると思っていたのに学ぶことになりました。分かりやすいご説明を本当に感謝しています。「が」があるかないかで意味がだいぶ違ってきますね。上記の文書を修正させていただきました。

Answer (score 8):

Both sentences are correct, but 見えます is more common.

見られます sounds a bit awkward to me, because the passive form of 見ます is also 見られます. ('to be seen' rather than 'can see')

You may also find people use 見れます ('見られます' without ら), which is often called ら抜き言葉 (ra-removed word). This is nonstandard and colloquial, and I personally avoid it whenever possible, but many people use this very often.